# Using a view controller for a game over scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I need to make an end screen for my app after the collision detection. What is the easiest possible way to make the end screen with a button back to the main menu/to the game. Can I use a `ViewController`? I've read a lot of tutorials, videos, and also all of the posts on here:

This is my current code (not all of it just some important things):

```
@implementation MyScene

static const int squirrelHitCategory = 1;
static const int nutHitCategory = 2;

- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    _squirrelSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"squirrel"];
    _squirrelSprite.position = _firstPosition;
    _atFirstPosition = YES;

    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = squirrelHitCategory;
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = nutHitCategory;
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  nutHitCategory;

    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    [self addChild:_squirrelSprite];

    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0];

        SKSpriteNode *lightnut = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"lightnut.png"];

        lightnut.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(200,160)];

        lightnut.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = nutHitCategory;
        lightnut.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = squirrelHitCategory;
        lightnut.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  squirrelHitCategory;

        lightnut.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

        [self addChild: lightnut];

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
// Check time since the last touch event
if (touch.timestamp-_lastTouch >= .9) {
    // Allow touch
    NSLog(@"greater than or equal to 3 seconds");

    if (_atFirstPosition)
    {
        SKAction *moveNodeLeft = [SKAction moveByX:-207.8 y:0.0 duration:0.85];
        [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeLeft withKey:@"moveleft"];
    } else {
        SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveByX:207.8 y:0.0 duration:0.85];
        [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeRight withKey:@"moveright"];
    }
    _atFirstPosition = !_atFirstPosition;
    _squirrelSprite.xScale *= -1.0;
}
else {
    // Ignore touch
    NSLog(@"Seconds since last touch %g",touch.timestamp-_lastTouch);
}
// Store timestamp
_lastTouch = touch.timestamp;

}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact

{
NSLog(@"contact detected");
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

firstBody = contact.bodyA;
secondBody = contact.bodyB;

if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == squirrelHitCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == nutHitCategory)
{

}
}
```

I want my end screen to be simple, so the easiest way to make it is best. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my games I add a UIViewController property and assign it to the SKScene.

You can then add a view as a sub view. Example...

```
SKScene *scene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:self.view.frame.size];
scene.viewController = self;
```

Then in your scene...

```
[self.viewController addSubview:yourView];
```

Here is some of my own game's implementation to help get you started.

In your Storyboard, or XIB whichever you prefer you add a view with buttons as properties of the view. In my case I have a scoreLabel, a menuButton, and a restartButton as properties and can set them all as x.hidden = YES; as I wish by triggering them in the scene such as...

```
self.vc.menuButton.hidden = YES;
self.vc.restartButton.hidden = YES;
```

In your GameViewController (Which is a subclass of UIViewController)...

```
//header
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *hudView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *menuButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *restartButton;

@property (nonatomic) MazeScene *maze;

@end

//class
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    // Debug Options
//    skView.showsFPS = YES;
//    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
//    skView.showsPhysics = YES;

    // Create and configure the maze scene.
    CGSize sceneSize = skView.bounds.size;
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    MazeScene *maze = [[MazeScene alloc] initWithSize:sceneSize];
    maze.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    maze.vc = self;
    [skView presentScene:maze];
    _maze = maze;
}
```

In your SKScene...

```
//header
@interface MazeScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) GameViewController *vc;

@end

//class
-(id) initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        //(GameViewController*) is a static cast of a subclass of UIViewController.
        [self.view addSubview:((GameViewController*)self.vc).hudView];
        // [self restartGame] is a specific method for my game, don't worry about it
        [self restartGame];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Are there any good tutorials on how to do this? I'm still very new to ios programming. Thank you!

Comment: @Ryanc I updated my answer with some of my own code to help get you started. I don't have a picture of my storyboard posted but if you need more help let me know.